# Changing currency in excel using a dropdown via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format, currency

I have some Excel VBA code which I can use a dropdown (F1) to change currency. It changes only one specified cell (H1). I would like the code to change the currency for the whole workbook. I do not know how to tell the code to change the currency for the whole workbook rather than just a cell H1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 On Error GoTo endit
       Application.EnableEvents = False
 With Me.Range("H1")
 Select Case Target.Value
    Case "USD"
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    Case "GBP"
        .NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
    Case "EUR"
        .NumberFormat = "€#,##0.00"
     End Select
End With
endit:
     Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through all sheets?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know specifically which cells/ranges need to have that format applied?  Presumably you don't want to format the entire workbook?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Im not a coder, im lost with this stuff. So to understand the best way is to define ranges? Do you know what code i can change to to define ranges?

Comment: Can you please expand on what you sugest by loops please?

Comment: Knowing which cells need the formatting applied is not a coding question: only you know where they are or how they can be located.  That is the "what" - code is the "how".

Answer (score 0):

You can group all target cells and name them as, say, "CurrencyFormattedCells" then, run the code (adapting it to your scenario):

```
Dim objCell As Excel.Range

For Each objCell In Range("CurrencyFormattedCells").Cells
    With objCell
        If VBA.IsNumeric(objCell) Then
            Select Case Target.Value
            Case "USD"
                .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            Case "GBP"
                .NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
            Case "EUR"
                .NumberFormat = "€#,##0.00"
            End Select
        End If
    End With
Next
```

It's worth mention that running the code here, in Brazil, Excel shows the resultant NumberFormat for "$#,##0.00" as R$ #.##0,00 (R$ = Real, Brazil's currency notation)

Comment: Thanks! I adapted the code with the named range for the sheet and its working great within the sheet, with this code:

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code with named ranges for the sheet and it is working very well just for the sheet (not the workbook) with this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 On Error GoTo endit
       Application.EnableEvents = False
 With Me.Range("CurrencyFormattedCells")
 Select Case Target.Value
    Case "USD"
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    Case "GBP"
        .NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
    Case "EUR"
        .NumberFormat = "€#,##0.00"
     End Select
End With
endit:
     Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

If I wanted to use the same code on another tab, how can I change the target (Target, Me.Range("F1")) to look at the other sheet reference cell with my dropdown.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` only fires for changes in that one sheet, so if you want to handle changes in another sheet then you need to add the same or similar code in that sheet's code module. Alternatively you can use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event in the `ThisWorkbook` module. That will be triggered by a change in any worksheet.